# apply a function to a row with condition

Tags: row, conditional-statements

i got this data frame

```
    x1  x2  x3
1  2.5 2.8 1.4
2  2.1 1.9 2.3
3  1.7 2.2 4.4
4  2.4 3.8 3.7
5  4.3 4.4 4.1
6  4.2 4.9 2.4
7  2.7 1.5 2.5
8  2.8 3.3 4.9
9  3.5 2.3 2.9
10 4.1 2.8 2.2
```

so i need to check for every row a condition and apply a function to this row so that the value of this function would be in the fourth column or in the external vector. i.e. if min_value_of_row < thrshld then min(row) else mean(row)

How would one do that?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I was looking for something similar. Firstly I would create two columns with `min` and `mean` values of each row with:

```
df['min'] = df.min(axis=1)
```

and

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

then build a function:

```
def f(x):
    thr = 2
    if x['min'] <= thr:
         x = x['min']
    else:
         x = x['mean']

    return x
```

and apply it to the dataframe row-wise (axis=1):

```
df['value'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

this returns:

```
     x1   x2   x3  value
1   2.5  2.8  1.4  1.400
2   2.1  1.9  2.3  1.900
3   1.7  2.2  4.4  1.700
4   2.4  3.8  3.7  3.075
5   4.3  4.4  4.1  4.225
6   4.2  4.9  2.4  3.475
7   2.7  1.5  2.5  1.500
8   2.8  3.3  4.9  3.450
9   3.5  2.3  2.9  2.750
10  4.1  2.8  2.2  2.825
```